# AngularJS resources - loading multiple resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple of simple resources in my resources module:

```
// resources/ResourceOnejs
angular.module('myApp.resources', []).factory('ResourceOne', function($resource) {
    return $resource(...);
});

// resources/ResourceTwo.js
angular.module('myApp.resources', []).factory('ResourceTwo', function($resource) {
    return $resource(...);
});
```

It seems like there can be only one of them used at a time.

i.e.

If I add ResourceTwo then "Unknown Provider" error when I try to inject ResourceOne, but once I remove ResourceTwo I am now able to inject ResourceTwo.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring the module with your syntax. Use this way

```
// resources/ResourceOnejs
angular.module('myApp.resources', []).factory('ResourceOne', function($resource) {
    return $resource(...);
});

// resources/ResourceTwo.js
angular.module('myApp.resources').factory('ResourceTwo', function($resource) {
    return $resource(...);
});
```

basically

```
angular.module('name',[]) //creates a new module
angular.module('name')  //gets the existing module
```